# user_save adds values to the user, but they aren't "active"

Tags: users

I'm taking over a website that had a user import; it has a function that sets the value for some Boolean fields on the user.

```
$user->field_perm_connexion['und'][0]['value'] = (int)$permissions['perm_connexion'];
user_save($user);
```

When I edit the user, the value is correctly checked; when I execute code like the following, the value is wrong.

```
$user_perm = user_load($uid);
// don't judge the ['und'][0]['value']
if(!empty($user_perm->field_perm_connexion) && $user_perm->field_perm_connexion['und'][0]['value'] == 1){
    $is_allowed = TRUE;
}
```

I need to go to the user page (in the people menu) and save again, to get the correct values.

What could the problem behind this be?

Answer (score 0):

It may be static cache, try:

```
$user_perm = user_load($uid, TRUE);
```